# R code to fetch Saudi Arabia map

Tags: r, ggmap

I am using the below R code but it gives me error

```
get_map(location="Saudi Arabia")
map_data("Saudi Arabia")
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(location = "saudi arabia", zoom = 6)
ggmap(map)

map_data("world", regions="saudi arabia")
```

[image]